# How to use FullCalendar resourceTimeGridDay in v 4.3.1?

Tags: javascript, angular, asp.net-mvc-5, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I'm using `resourcetimegrid` plugin, but it only works when I use `defaultView:'resourceDayGridDay'` and for sure it only shows the day without showing the hours, but I want to use `resourceTimeGridDay` to be able to see the hours.

This code works for `resourceDayGridDay`, but the hours don't show up.

```js
var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
        schedulerLicenseKey: 'GPL-My-Project-Is-Open-Source',
        plugins: ['interaction', 'resourceDayGrid', 'resourceTimeGrid'],
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'resourceDayGridDay'
        },
        defaultView: 'resourceDayGridDay',
        resources: [
            { id: 'a', title: 'Rampa 1' },
            { id: 'b', title: 'Rampa 2', eventColor: 'green' },
            { id: 'c', title: 'Rampa 3', eventColor: 'orange' },
            { id: 'd', title: 'Rampa 4', eventColor: 'red' },
            { id: 'e', title: 'Rampa 5', eventColor: 'red' },
            { id: 'f', title: 'Rampa 6', eventColor: 'red' },
            { id: 'g', title: 'Rampa 7', eventColor: 'red' },
            { id: 'h', title: 'Rampa 8', eventColor: 'red' }
        ],
        events: [
            { id: '1', resourceId: 'b', start: '2020-02-05T02:00:00', end: '2020-02-05T07:00:00', title: 'event 1' },
            { id: '2', resourceId: 'c', start: '2020-02-05T05:00:00', end: '2020-02-05T22:00:00', title: 'event 2' },
            { id: '3', resourceId: 'd', start: '2020-02-05', end: '2020-02-05', title: 'event 3' },
            { id: '4', resourceId: 'a', start: '2020-02-05T03:00:00', end: '2020-02-05T08:00:00', title: 'event 4' },
            { id: '5', resourceId: 'b', start: '2020-02-05T00:30:00', end: '2020-02-05T02:30:00', title: 'event 5' }

        ],
        selectable: true,
        editable: true,
        nowIndicator: true,
        minTime: "06:00:00",
        maxTime: "30:00:00",
        droppable: true
    });

    calendar.render();
};
```

When I change the `defaultView` to: `resourceTimeGridDay` it throws:

> TypeError: Unable to get property 'ResourceDayGrid' of undefined or null reference
> at ResourceTimeGridView (http://localhost/App/Scripts/packages/resource-timegrid/main.js:146:17)

```js
var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
        schedulerLicenseKey: 'GPL-My-Project-Is-Open-Source',
        plugins: ['interaction', 'resourceDayGrid', 'resourceTimeGrid'],
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'resourceTimeGridDay'
        },
        defaultView: 'resourceTimeGridDay',
        resources: [
            { id: 'a', title: 'Room 1' },
            { id: 'b', title: 'Room 2', eventColor: 'green' },
            { id: 'c', title: 'Room 3', eventColor: 'orange' },
            { id: 'd', title: 'Room 4', eventColor: 'red' },
            { id: 'e', title: 'Room 5', eventColor: 'red' },
            { id: 'f', title: 'Room 6', eventColor: 'red' },
            { id: 'g', title: 'Room 7', eventColor: 'red' },
            { id: 'h', title: 'Room 8', eventColor: 'red' }
        ],
        events: [
            { id: '1', resourceId: 'b', start: '2020-02-05T02:00:00', end: '2020-02-05T07:00:00', title: 'event 1' },
            { id: '2', resourceId: 'c', start: '2020-02-05T05:00:00', end: '2020-02-05T22:00:00', title: 'event 2' },
            { id: '3', resourceId: 'd', start: '2020-02-05', end: '2020-02-05', title: 'event 3' },
            { id: '4', resourceId: 'a', start: '2020-02-05T03:00:00', end: '2020-02-05T08:00:00', title: 'event 4' },
            { id: '5', resourceId: 'b', start: '2020-02-05T00:30:00', end: '2020-02-05T02:30:00', title: 'event 5' }

        ],
        selectable: true,
        editable: true,
        nowIndicator: true,
        minTime: "06:00:00",
        maxTime: "30:00:00",
        droppable: true
    });

    calendar.render();
};
```

My scripts in BundleConfig.cs for JS:

```
                "~/Scripts/packages/core/main.js",
                "~/Scripts/packages/daygrid/main.js",
                "~/Scripts/packages/interaction/main.js",
                "~/Scripts/packages/timegrid/main.js",
                //"~/Scripts/packages/list/main.js",

                "~/Scripts/packages/resource-common/main.js",
                "~/Scripts/packages/resource-timegrid/main.js",
                "~/Scripts/packages/resource-daygrid/main.js"
```

and CSS:

```
                "~/Scripts/packages/core/main.css",
                "~/Scripts/packages/daygrid/main.css",
                "~/Scripts/packages/timegrid/main.css",
                //"~/Scripts/packages/list/main.css",
                "~/Scripts/packages/external-events/external-events.css"
```

Using: fullcalendar-4.3.1.zip

Answer (score 1):

Just move `"~/Scripts/packages/resource-daygrid/main.js"` above `"~/Scripts/packages/resource-timegrid/main.js"` in BundleConfig.cs, I think, so it's loaded first.

The error is complaining that resourceTimeGrid can't find resourceDayGrid (on which it depends). That would make sense, if resourceDayGrid is being loaded later.

So you'd end up with

```
...
"~/Scripts/packages/resource-common/main.js",
"~/Scripts/packages/resource-daygrid/main.js"
"~/Scripts/packages/resource-timegrid/main.js",
```